# Update (Oracle) DB with Data from Excel

Tags: python, excel, oracle, plsql

I have a Oracle table like this: Order_ID, Project_ID.
Order_ID is the primary key.
Project_ID supposed to have a values but left null in many cases.
Now I have a list of Order_ID and Project_ID which is the correct data, but that is in excel.
I have to update my oracle database for matching projects as below:

Bad Data on my Oracle Database:

```
Order_ID, Project_ID
1000,     20090
1001,     null
1002,     null
```

Correct Data provided in Excel:

```
Order_ID, Project_ID
1001,     22565
1002,     25548
```

Updated Data in Oracle Database should look like:

```
Order_ID, Project_ID
1000,     20090
1001,     22565
1002,     25548
```

Please remember I am not looking for the sql statement to do it for each ids/lines, rather imagine I have millions of updates to make and want to automate it with a loop.

I am comfortable to use PL/SQL and Python, but other technologies are also welcome.

Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

There are various approaches to load from a excel. You could convert it to a csv and load via SQL* Loader, Use third party packages to load excel, use external table etc. But, a simple method is to use SQL developer. Here is an article from Jeff Smith that describes how to do it.

[**Import from Excel**](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/)

For your convenience, 
Create a `_tmp` table with the same structure as that of Orders table and dump the excel onto it.

```
Create table Orders_tmp as select * FROM Orders where 1=0;
```

Then use a simple `MERGE` statement to correct the records in the main `Orders` table.

```
MERGE INTO ORDERS t
USING Orders_tmp s
    ON (t.order_id = s.order_id)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET t.project_id = s.project_id;
```